# Upsert object B record on insert of object A record

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

There are 2 objects. Object A and object B with same fields. There is no relationship between them (no lookup). When a record is inserted in object A, object B should be checked to see if the same record exists. If it exists then update it else create a new one. How do I do this. Can some one please provide some sample code or an example that would be great.  Please assist.

Regards,
Sfdcdev

Comment: Define "Same record object B". How do you determine that it's the same? Every field of B has the same value as a field with the same API name on object A?

Comment: Hi Egor,Api names are different. but same schema. Field values will be same.

Comment: If the API names are different, how do you know which fields to compare? And doesn't a schema include the field names? If the names are different, I wouldn't say that the two objects share the same schema.

Comment: The field data types are same. Text1 field exists in object A and also in B